# Evil-leader stops working when I eval-buffer

Tags: evil

If I load up emacs and go to my .emacs file (a fragment of which is given below), and I press SPC f or C-c C-f then it does find-file, which is the expected behaviour. However, if I type M-x eval-buffer, or load-file, suddenly SPC f doesn't work, but C-c C-f still does. If I press SPC, it just goes to the next character as it would without evil-leader. What gives?

```
(require 'evil) 
(evil-mode 1)

(require 'evil-leader)
(global-evil-leader-mode)

(evil-leader/set-leader "<SPC>")

(evil-leader/set-key "f" 'find-file)
```

(x-posted from superuser.com)

Comment: Comment deleted, as my suggestion didn't work regardless.

Comment: You can't prove this false because you don't have access to my machine. I'm still having this error. I am using `eval-buffer` and `load-file` and they both have the same effect. Perhaps it has something to do with my setup somehow?

Comment: Here's my .emacs file: http://pastebin.com/fZp5Ddk7

Comment: I can confirm that I can reproduce this with your `init` file, but I don't know what to suggest. When working with evil-mode, I've had problems redefining keys in the `evil-normal-state` map. But it's bizarre that simply re-evaluating the `init` file results in different behaviour.

Comment: Try switching the order of enabling evil-leader and evil. The global-evil-leader-mode sets up a hook which is likely not run if evil is already active.

Comment: Hi @DanielSatanove, I've tried justbur's solution, and I think it's fixed the problem. Can you confirm?

Comment: @adc Yes, that indeed works. If someone writes it up I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Super, well it was @justbur 's solution so the points should go him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`global-evil-leader-mode` adds a function to enable `evil-leader-mode` through the hook `evil-local-mode-hook`. This means that `evil-leader-mode` is enabled in a buffer after enabling `evil-local-mode`.

In your case, you are enabling `evil-local-mode` (through the global `evil-mode`) and then adding to the hook, meaning the hook is run before you added the `evil-leader-mode` function to it. If you reverse the order of `(global-evil-leader-mode)` and `(evil-mode 1)`, the problem will be fixed.